# jQuery plugin for floating popup

Tags: jquery, facebook

Is there any jQuery plugin which does this:

[image]

I don't know the English name of this function, if I knew it I would search for it myself.

Comment: Are you talking about the tooltip effect?  The little box that appears on mouseover of the lock?

Comment: Assuming I know what you mean, then the word you are looking for is "tooltip": http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+tooltip

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a tooltip.
Search google for jquery tooltip.  I did and found this
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Looked like a good start.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It's called ToolTip. Look here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

I already used this one, looks great and it's easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of them, but I've personally used this one and it's excellent:

[jQuery Tools ToolTip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html)

Comment: I totally posted this link 1 minute before you `:)`

Comment: And I thought I had `nimble` fingers too.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Tools tooltips moved to

http://jquerytools.org/

Demo:

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip